# How can I get all email which are all under condition back in stock email alert?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, inventory

I need to get all email at once which are all click notify about back in stock condition. How can I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a customer clicks on **Sign up to get notified when this product is back in stock**, the customer id is saved in the `product_alert_stock` table.

You can get the customer id using this model:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock');
```

Here is code to get a customer's email address:

```
  $collection = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')->getCollection();
  $collection->getSelect()->join( array('customer'=> customer_entity), 'customer.entity_id = main_table.customer_id', array('customer.email'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an event that checks if the product quantity is updated or not.

Add this code in the configuration file:

```
<catalog_product_save_before>
    <observers>
        <catalog_product_save_after_action_handler>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>module/observer</class>
            <method>backinstock</method>
        </catalog_product_save_after_action_handler>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_save_before>
```

Create an Observer, make a backinstock function and add this code:

```
public function checkchange($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $id = $product->getId();
    $oldproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

    // Get old price and quantity

    $oldPrice = $oldproduct->getPrice();
    $productname = $oldproduct->getName();
    $url = $oldproduct->getProductUrl();
    $oldQty = $oldproduct->getStockItem()->getQty();

    // Get new price and quantity

    $newPrice = $_POST['product']['price'];
    $newQty = $_POST['product']['stock_data']['qty'];

    if($oldQty == 0 && $newQty > $oldQty)
    {
        if($available == 1)
        {
            $emailTemplateVariables = array('price' => $newPrice,'name'=>$productname, 'url' =>$url);

            // Appending the Custom Variables to Template.
            $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
            $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
                ->setToName('test')
                ->setToEmail('test@test.com')
                ->setBody($processedTemplate)
                ->setSubject('Regarding your product back in stock')
                ->setFromEmail('test@test.com')
                ->setFromName('Store')
                ->setType('html');

            $mail->send();
        }
    }
}
```

You can get email for your product back in stock.